# Linking two tables to find a record only if there isn't a record in another table

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have two tables...

```
tbl1
ClientNo        ApptID          Status
1234            1               121
1234            2               121
1235            1               121
1235            2               121


tbl2
ClientNo        Valid         
1234            17
```

I'm looking to select all clients from tbl1 - where ApptID = 2, and there is no corresponding record in tbl2. So based on this data, 1234 has a record in tbl2, then no need to display it in end result.

I would love to see this as the end result:

```
ClientNo        ApptID          Status
1235            2               121
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl1 AS t1
WHERE t1.ApptID = 2 AND  
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl2 AS t2
                  WHERE t1.ClientNo = t2.ClientNo )
```

Comment: Yours was first that did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the join field to NULL

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tbl1 t1
   LEFT JOIN tbl_2 t2
   ON t1.ClientNo = t2.ClientNo 
   WHERE t1.ApptID=2 AND t2.ClientNo IS NULL
```

Or use sub-query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
   WHERE ApptID=2 AND ClientNo NOT IN (SELECT ClientNo FROM tbl_2)
```

Comment: Get a syntax error near where' Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.'

Comment: I have updated the answer and added one more approach

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below answer:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL2 T2
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE ApptID = 2) TBL T1
ON T2.ClientNo = T1.ClientNo 
WHERE T2.ClientNo IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked and answered a lot of times:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5840232/1334425
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076157/1334425
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6528786/1334425
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6613752/1334425
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6601945/1334425

You need to join with a first condition matching and a second condition which specifies the *failed* match:

```
SELECT t1.ClientNo
  FROM tbl1 t1
  LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON
    t1.ClientNo = t2.ClientNo
    AND t1.ClientNo IS NULL
```